# Asymptote and a function

Tags: calculus, functions

If the line $x=1$ is a vertical asymptote to a function, $f(x)$, then is it true that $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=1$.

Can you lighten me with an example, also? I think it's true??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not generally true. Rather than "$f$ is undefined at $x=1$", it is generally the case that "$f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$". We see that:

$$f:\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R : f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x-1} & x\neq 1 \\  0 & x=1 \end{cases}$$

is defined at $x=1$, but not continuous.

Comment: Can you give me an example when $f(x)$ is not defined at the point.

Comment: Cut out $x=1$ from my function, so $$f:\Bbb R/\{1\}\mapsto\Bbb R : f(x) =\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

If the line whith equation $ x=1$ is a vertical asymptote, this means that when $ x $ goes to $ 1 $, $ f(x) $ goes to infinity :
$$\lim_{x\to 1,x> 1}f(x)=\pm \infty$$
or
$$\lim_{x\to 1, x<1}f(x)=\pm \infty$$

this limit does not depend on the fact that $ f(1) $ exists or not.

Example 1:
$$\forall x\ne 1\;\; f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Example 2:
$$\forall x\ne 1 \;\; f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})$$
$$ \text{ and } f(1)=0$$

Comment: So, the $f(1)$ can either exist or not exist, I got it.